# EGIT: cannot resolve ORIG_HEAD

Tags: egit

When I try to use `merge tool` 
[image: merge tool in context menu]

it's not working and show for me following error dialog.
[image: cannot resolve ORIG_HEAD]

Answer (score 0):

There is no git reference `ORIG_HEAD` created, which should point to the commit that was checked out before a merge or rebase operation was started.

Comment: Yes ORIG_HEAD is missing but what is the best way to solve this problem?